# Why does GitBash create a file named "1" when I use my alias?

Tags: alias, git-bash

So I wanted to create an alias that opens a new GitBash terminal at the current location. I looked it up and found this command

```
/git-bash.exe & > /dev/null 2&>1
```

I added it to aliases.sh like so: [image]

The command works just fine. It opens a new bash terminal at the current directory like I wanted, But it always creates a file called "1" with command not found: [image]

I tried removing the `2&>1` part but that did nothing.

Comment: Move the `&` at the end of the alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using what Joachim Sauer said: "Move the & at the end of the alias"